# How to declare a custom theming function for block content?

Tags: 7, theming

My goal is to render an array of values (body, date) using my own theming function.  I've read [Using the theme layer](http://drupal.org/node/933976), and checked out the example modules, and I can't see the reason why this isn't outputting the test string.

I've implemented registered my theme hook:

```
function mymod_theme() {
    $items = array(
        'mymod_items' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'items'=>NULL
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I've implemented a theme function:

```
function theme_mymod_items($variables) {
    return 'I am themed output';
}
```

And I call this from my `hook_block_view`:

```
function mymod_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch($delta) {
        case 'mymod':
            $block['subject'] = t('My Module');
            $items = array(
                array('body'=>'body1','time'=>'time1'),
                array('body'=>'body2','time'=>'time2'),
                array('body'=>'body3','time'=>'time3'),
            );
            $block['content'] = theme('mymod_items',$items);
        break;  
    }
    return $block;
}
```

This results in the block not displaying, and the following message turning up in the log:

> Theme key "mymod_items" not found.

Can someone please tell me what obviously essential step I've missed, or if I'm going in entirely the wrong direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an obvious answer, so sorry if you've tried it, but have you cleared your cache, specifically the theme registry?

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing.